# ESP8266 Tcp-to-uart with reprogramming ability

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I'm using this example from nodemcu repo:

```
uart.setup(0,9600,8,0,1,0)
sv=net.createServer(net.TCP, 60)
global_c = nil
sv:listen(9999, function(c)
    if global_c~=nil then
        global_c:close()
    end
    global_c=c
    c:on("receive",function(sck,pl) uart.write(0,pl) end)
end)

uart.on("data",4, function(data)
    if global_c~=nil then
        global_c:send(data)
    end
end, 0)
```

But, since I'm using uart module, I'm no longer able to communicate with my chip via LuaLoader and can not upload updated `init.lua` files. Instead, I have to put chip into flash-upload mode, then flash initial nodemcu firmware and then my updated `init.lua`. Too much steps.

How can I retain ability to communicate via LuaLoader? I've tried something like this:

```
uart.on('data', '\n', handleUartResponse, 0)
...
...
function handleUartResponse(response)
    if response == 'flash\n' then
        g_flash = true
        toggleOutput(true)
        uart.write(0, 'flash mode')

    elseif response == 'endflash\n' then    
        g_flash = false 
        uart.write(0, 'normal mode')
        toggleOutput(false)

    elseif g_flash then
        node.input(response)

    else
        if g_conn ~= nil then
            g_conn:send(response, function(sock)
                closeConnection(sock)
                g_conn = nil
            end)
        end
    end
end

function toggleOutput(turnOn) 
    if turnOn then
        node.output(nil, 1)
    else
        node.output(silent, 0)
    end
end
```

It prints `flash mode` and `normal mode` in another serial terminal, but it doesn't work in LuaLoader. I think the problem is in uart setup, maybe it should not be `\n`, but other condition, I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Not sure if it is the best option, since I'm new to lua, but it works.

```
function handleNormalMode(response)
    if response == 'flash\r' then -- magic code to enter interpreter mode
        toggleFlash(true)        
    else -- tcp-to-uart
        if g_conn ~= nil then
            g_conn:send(response, function(sock)
                closeConnection(sock)
                g_conn = nil
            end)
        end
    end
end

function ignore(x)
end

function uartSetup(echo)
    uart.setup(0, 115200, 8, 0, 1, echo)
end

function toggleFlash(turnOn) 
    if turnOn then
        uart.on('data')  -- unregister old callback
        uartSetup(1) -- re-configure uart
        uart.on('data', 0, ignore, 1) -- this allows lua interpreter to work
        node.output(nil) -- turn on lua output to uart
        uart.write(0, 'flash mode') -- notify user
    else
        node.output(ignore, 0) -- turn off lua output to uart
        uart.on('data') -- unregister old callback
        uartSetup(0) -- re-configure uart
        uart.on('data', '\r', handleNormalMode, 0) -- turn on tcp-to-uart
        uart.write(0, 'normal mode') -- notify user
    end
end
```

I'm calling `toggleFlash(false)` at the beginning of script. Then, typing `flash\r` enters lua interpreter mode and to switch back I'm just typing `toggleFlash(false)` and it works! That simplifies updating `init.lua` every time.